# CSS web page width, nav bar centering & widget wrap centering

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm fairly new to CSS. As you can see, my web page currently has a lot of space to the left and right of my content, making my navigation bar very long. I'd like to set this to be less wide without effecting how responsive my theme is on mobile or tablet.

I'd also like to centre the social media icons/widget at the top beneath my logo, and to center the links in my navigation bar.

Website here:

http://aspectcopywriting.co.uk/

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While the CSS in Emily's answer does work, it's not the proper way to center a div. According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) you should use width and margin on the element that holds the social icons and navigation tabs you wish to center, as seen below:

```
.social_container{
  width: 225px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_links_container{
  width: 605px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center those items within their parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is pretty easy. All you need to do is select the `div` where you wrapped up your social media icons and use the properties `text-align` with value `center`. Like this:

```
.widget_catchresponsive_social_icons {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Everything should be centered now!
For some more reference check in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):